# Printing numbers as words

Tags: c

How can I print the digits of a number input from a user as words?  For example, suppose I input a number `123` then I want the line "one-two-three" to be printed.

Below is my attempt:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0,a,c,o=0,p;

    printf("enter the number you want ");

    scanf("%d",&a);
    c=a;


    while(a !=0)
    {
        a=a/10;
        i++;
    }
    while(o<=i)
    {
        p=c%10;
        c=c/10;
        if(p==1)
        printf(" one ");
        else if(p==2)
        printf(" two ");
        else if(p==3)
        printf(" three ");
        else if(p==4)
        printf(" four ");
        else if(p==5)
        printf(" five ");
        else if(p==6)
        printf(" six ");
        else if(p==7)
        printf(" seven ");
        else if(p==8)
        printf(" eight " );
        else if(p==9)
        printf(" nine ");
        else if(p==0)
        printf(" zero ");

        o++;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is printing an extra zero.  How can I fix this?

Comment: What did you try so far ? You might find the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) interesting

Comment: What about a short search with your favourite search engine. For example read: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Simple_input_and_output

Comment: Where exactly are you having a problem? Do you know how to write a simple C program, such as "Hello, world"? If so, do you know how to read input from a user as a number or a string? Do you know how to print a string? Do you know how to use an array? Your question gives the impression that you really need to hit a text book and/or a tutorial first, then ask something more specific. This isn't a language fundamentals tutorial site.

Comment: @MichaelWalz no, he wants to display the numbers as letters

Comment: @Rafalon OK, on a second read I understand what he wants ;-)

Comment: @MichaelWalz yeah, I would've added block quotes around `one-two-three` but that would be a 2-characters edit, and I can't do that

Comment: The general steps could be: (1) read the number from the user, (2) create a loop to step through the digits of the number, (3) inside the loop map the digit to the string representing the digit (e.g., "one", "two", etc) and print that, (4) also inside the loop, print a "-" if you need to (you aren't out of digits yet). That's a simple approach. There are various ways of accomplishing some of these steps.

Comment: Oh, right.  Get the chars with sprintf or something.  Subtrct '0' to get the bin. value, and use that to index a const array of char* to const strings.

Comment: Like this: const char * const numberText[] = {
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"};

Comment: "It is printing an extra zero. How can I fix this?" --> Post the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra zero is coming from here:

```
while(o<=i)
```

`i` is the number of digits.  Since `o` starts at 0 it ranges from 0 to `i`, so you go through the loop one extra time.  At that point, `c` is 0, so that's what gets printed.

You can fix this by changing your condition:

```
while(o<i)
```

There is another issue, however.  This program prints the words in the reverse order.  You can fix this by saving the digits in an array, then looping backward through that array to print the digits.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0,a,p;
    int digits[25];  // enough for a 64-bit number
    // list of digits names that can be indexed easily
    char *numberStr[] = { " zero ", " one ", " two ", " three ", " four ", 
                          " five ", " six ", " seven ", " eight ", " nine " };

    printf("enter the number you want ");

    scanf("%d",&a);

    while(a !=0)
    {
        // save each digit in the array
        digits[i] = a%10;
        a=a/10;
        i++;
    }
    i--;   // back off i to contain the index of the highest order digit

    // loop through the array in reverse
    while(i>=0)
    {
        p=digits[i];
        printf("%s", numberStr[i]);
        i--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dbush . Other people kinda like killed my curiosity. Thanks for the support.